# How to find publisher of a signedJar file?

Tags: java, security, sign, java-security

I have few jar files that are signed. I am able to verify the signing using jarsigner. How do I find the publisher of the jar file? I would like to check if the jar file is signed by the appropriate trusted certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: use `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs some.jar`.

The `-verbose` and `-certs`, the output of `jarsigner -verify` will include certificate information for each of the signers found in the JAR file.  If X509 certs were used, then the information includes the distinguished name information for the signer.

Here is some example output taken from the manual page:

```
jarsigner -keystore /working/mystore -verify -verbose -certs myTest.jar
          198 Fri Sep 26 16:14:06 PDT 1997 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
          199 Fri Sep 26 16:22:10 PDT 1997 META-INF/JANE.SF
         1013 Fri Sep 26 16:22:10 PDT 1997 META-INF/JANE.DSA
          208 Fri Sep 26 16:23:30 PDT 1997 META-INF/JAVATEST.SF
         1087 Fri Sep 26 16:23:30 PDT 1997 META-INF/JAVATEST.DSA
   smk   2752 Fri Sep 26 16:12:30 PDT 1997 Tst.class
     X.509, CN=Test Group, OU=Java Software, O=Oracle, L=CUP, S=CA, C=US (javatest)
     X.509, CN=Jane Smith, OU=Java Software, O=Oracle, L=cup, S=ca, C=us (jane)
     s = signature was verified
     m = entry is listed in manifest
     k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
   jar verified.
```

Of course, the "appropriateness" of a signing authority can only be judged by a human.